# ShareX send capture to program like Outlook, Word, OneNote

Tags: microsoft-outlook, screenshot, capture, sharex

I am looking for a solution to send the capture / screenshot directly to a program / app like word, outlook or onenote.
In the actions example there is paint.exe
Save the capture and then open it in paint.
I wont it to clipboard and insert to word.

Can you help me?

Thanks, bye spooner

---

yes I can copy the capture to the clipboard and paste it to Outlook.
But I am searching the function in ShareX like Greenshot
[Greenshot send to...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPe2Z.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Any updates on the issue?

Answer (score -1):

What is the version of your outlook version and windows version?

In outlook side, you could send the screenshot to outlook, steps for your reference:
[image]

In word, you could copy the screenshot from paint tool and paste in word.